# How to get web store tab -> associated image sub-tab or web store tab fields in Item save search result?

Tags: netsuite

How to get web store tab -> associated images sub-tab or web store tab fields in Item save search result

[image: Image shows inventory item web store tab Associated images sub-tab]
[image: Image shows item save search]

Answer (score 0):

> web store tab -> associated images sub-tab

Is *Associated Images* a custom record? If yes, you will need to use join parameter(using SuiteScript) or while creating saved-search from UI, you can find custom-record fields at the end of the list containing something like *Associated Images Fields* to fetch fields if your search is on item.

> web store tab fields

If the fields are item body fields and not on some sublist, you will find the field directly in columns list.

Comment: thanks for answering but we don't get either in the end of the list containing something like Associated Images Fields and find the field directly in columns list.also not showing it is a custom record.

Comment: I too am trying to do this same thing & have no answers yet, except that Associated Images is not a custom record, in the console it appears to be an array stored as lineitems.itemimages; however, plugging in a formula(text) with {lineitems.itemimages} or {itemimages} or {itemimages.name} does not yeild any results  in my saved search. The array in my company's build of NetSuite stores the image data as ["nkey", "name", "altTagCaption", "siteList"]. In chrome dev tools console type nlapiLoadRecord(nlapiGetRecordType(),nlapiGetRecordId()) to get a full list of a record's fields and line items.